# google cloud function import errors in function view log

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have create a google cloud function in python runtime environment which is triggered by the google cloud pubsub and i have also add requirement dependencies but when i run the function it works properly but it logged some import error so how do i solve this problem.

python code :

```
import base64
import json

from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient import discovery
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError


class IotDevice:
    def __init__(self, service_account_json, project_id, cloud_region, registry_id, device_id):
        api_scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform']
        api_version = 'v1'
        discovery_api = 'https://cloudiot.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest'
        service_name = 'cloudiotcore'

        credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(service_account_json)
        scoped_credentials = credentials.with_scopes(api_scopes)

        discovery_url = '{}?version={}'.format(discovery_api, api_version)

        self.client = discovery.build(service_name, api_version, discoveryServiceUrl=discovery_url,
                                      credentials=scoped_credentials)
        self.project_id = project_id
        self.cloud_region = cloud_region
        self.registry_id = registry_id
        self.device_id = device_id

    def set_config(self, version, config):
        device_path = 'projects/{}/locations/{}/registries/{}/devices/{}'.format(
            self.project_id, self.cloud_region, self.registry_id, self.device_id)

        config_body = {
            'versionToUpdate': version,
            'binaryData': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(config.encode('utf-8')).decode('ascii')
        }

        try:
            return self.client.projects().locations().registries().devices().modifyCloudToDeviceConfig(
                name=device_path, body=config_body).execute()
        except HttpError as e:
            print(e.content.decode())

    def get_config_versions(self):
        registry_name = 'projects/{}/locations/{}/registries/{}'.format(
            self.project_id, self.cloud_region, self.registry_id)

        device_name = '{}/devices/{}'.format(registry_name, self.device_id)
        devices = self.client.projects().locations().registries().devices()
        configs = devices.configVersions().list(name=device_name).execute().get('deviceConfigs', [])

        return configs[0].get('version')
        # [END iot_get_device_configs]


def main(data, context):
    if data is not None:
        payload = base64.b64decode(data['data']).decode('utf-8')
        payload = json.loads(payload)
        attributes = data['attributes']
        project_id = attributes['projectId']
        location = attributes['deviceRegistryLocation']
        registry_id = attributes['deviceRegistryId']
        device_id = attributes['deviceId']

        device = IotDevice('./service_account.json', project_id, location, registry_id, device_id)
        config_version = device.get_config_versions()
        value = payload["value"]
        thresold = payload["thresold"]
        if value > thresold:
            config = json.dumps({'action': 'ON'})
        else:
            config = json.dumps({'action': 'OFF'})
        device.set_config(version=config_version, config=config)
```

requirement.txt

```
google-api-python-client==1.7.8
google-auth==1.6.2


 main 512547093010642 Function execution started D  main 512547093010642
 main 512547093010642 file_cache is unavailable when using oauth2client >= 4.0.0 or google-auth E  main 512547093010642
 main 512547093010642 Traceback (most recent call last): E  main 512547093010642
 main 512547093010642   File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/__init__.py", line 36, in autodetect E  main 512547093010642
 main 512547093010642     from google.appengine.api import memcache E  main 512547093010642
 main 512547093010642 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.appengine' E  main 512547093010642
 main 512547093010642 {"insertId":"000005-70ff3337-da0f-440d-8fa3-d520879375ef","resource":{"type":"cloud_function","labels":{"region":"us-central1","function_name":"main","project_id":"robot-11"}},"timestamp":"2019-04-17T05:23:53.316Z","severity":"ERROR","labels":{"execution_id":"512547093010642"},"logName":"projects/ro… E  main 512547093010642
 main 512547093010642 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: E  main 512547093010642
 main 512547093010642 {"insertId":"000007-70ff3337-da0f-440d-8fa3-d520879375ef","resource":{"type":"cloud_function","labels":{"function_name":"main","project_id":"robot-11","region":"us-central1"}},"timestamp":"2019-04-17T05:23:53.316Z","severity":"ERROR","labels":{"execution_id":"512547093010642"},"logName":"projects/ro… E  main 512547093010642
 main 512547093010642 Traceback (most recent call last): E  main 512547093010642
 main 512547093010642   File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/file_cache.py", line 33, in <module> E  main 512547093010642
 main 512547093010642     from oauth2client.contrib.locked_file import LockedFile E  main 512547093010642
 main 512547093010642 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'oauth2client' E  main 512547093010642
 main 512547093010642 {"insertId":"000012-70ff3337-da0f-440d-8fa3-d520879375ef","resource":{"type":"cloud_function","labels":{"project_id":"robot-11","region":"us-central1","function_name":"main"}},"timestamp":"2019-04-17T05:23:53.316Z","severity":"ERROR","labels":{"execution_id":"512547093010642"},"logName":"projects/ro… E  main 512547093010642
 main 512547093010642 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: E  main 512547093010642
 main 512547093010642 {"insertId":"000014-70ff3337-da0f-440d-8fa3-d520879375ef","resource":{"type":"cloud_function","labels":{"project_id":"robot-11","region":"us-central1","function_name":"main"}},"timestamp":"2019-04-17T05:23:53.316Z","severity":"ERROR","labels":{"execution_id":"512547093010642"},"logName":"projects/ro… E  main 512547093010642
 main 512547093010642 Traceback (most recent call last): E  main 512547093010642
 main 512547093010642   File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/file_cache.py", line 37, in <module> E  main 512547093010642
 main 512547093010642     from oauth2client.locked_file import LockedFile E  main 512547093010642
 main 512547093010642 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'oauth2client' E  main 512547093010642
 main 512547093010642 {"insertId":"000019-70ff3337-da0f-440d-8fa3-d520879375ef","resource":{"type":"cloud_function","labels":{"project_id":"robot-11","region":"us-central1","function_name":"main"}},"timestamp":"2019-04-17T05:23:53.316Z","severity":"ERROR","labels":{"execution_id":"512547093010642"},"logName":"projects/ro… E  main 512547093010642
 main 512547093010642 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: E  main 512547093010642
 main 512547093010642 {"insertId":"000021-70ff3337-da0f-440d-8fa3-d520879375ef","resource":{"type":"cloud_function","labels":{"function_name":"main","project_id":"robot-11","region":"us-central1"}},"timestamp":"2019-04-17T05:23:53.316Z","severity":"ERROR","labels":{"execution_id":"512547093010642"},"logName":"projects/ro… E  main 512547093010642
 main 512547093010642 Traceback (most recent call last): E  main 512547093010642
 main 512547093010642   File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/__init__.py", line 41, in autodetect E  main 512547093010642
 main 512547093010642     from . import file_cache E  main 512547093010642
 main 512547093010642   File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/file_cache.py", line 41, in <module> E  main 512547093010642
 main 512547093010642     'file_cache is unavailable when using oauth2client >= 4.0.0 or google-auth') E  main 512547093010642
 main 512547093010642 ImportError: file_cache is unavailable when using oauth2client >= 4.0.0 or google-auth E  main 512547093010642
 main 512547093010642 URL being requested: GET https://cloudiot.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1 I  main 512547093010642
 main 512547093010642 URL being requested: GET https://cloudiot.googleapis.com/v1/projects/robot-11/locations/us-central1/registries/tour-registry/devices/fan/configVersions?alt=json I  main 512547093010642
 main 512547093010642 URL being requested: POST https://cloudiot.googleapis.com/v1/projects/robot-11/locations/us-central1/registries/tour-registry/devices/fan:modifyCloudToDeviceConfig?alt=json I  main 512547093010642
 main 512547093010642 Function execution took 627 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either suppress the log message:

```
import logging

logging.getLogger('googleapicliet.discovery_cache').setLevel(logging.ERROR)`
```

Or set `cache_discovery=False` when using `discovery.build()`:

```
self.client = discovery.build(
    service_name,
    api_version,
    discoveryServiceUrl=discovery_url,
    credentials=scoped_credentials,
    cache_discovery=False,
)
```